# Curtin error on autoinstall Ubuntu 20.04.1

Tags: apt, 20.04, subiquity

It fails when I try to use a local focal mirror or if I set a proxy. Here is the install log snippet:

```
2020-12-01 13:47:16,916 DEBUG root:39 start: subiquity/InstallProgress/install/curtin_install/cmd-install/stage-curthooks: configuring installed system
2020-12-01 13:47:16,918 DEBUG root:39 start: subiquity/InstallProgress/install/curtin_install/cmd-install/stage-curthooks/000-configure-run: running '/snap/bin/subiquity.subiquity-configure-run'
2020-12-01 13:47:16,919 DEBUG root:39 finish: subiquity/InstallProgress/install/curtin_install/cmd-install/stage-curthooks/000-configure-run: SUCCESS: Status.SUCCESS
2020-12-01 13:47:16,925 DEBUG root:39 start: subiquity/InstallProgress/install/curtin_install/cmd-install/stage-curthooks/001-configure-apt: running '/snap/bin/subiquity.subiquity-configure-apt /snap/subiquity/1966/usr/bin/python3 true'
2020-12-01 13:47:17,503 DEBUG root:39 start: subiquity/InstallProgress/install/curtin_install/cmd-install/stage-curthooks/001-configure-apt/cmd-apt-config: curtin command apt-config
2020-12-01 13:47:17,508 DEBUG root:39 finish: subiquity/InstallProgress/install/curtin_install/cmd-install/stage-curthooks/001-configure-apt/cmd-apt-config: SUCCESS: Status.SUCCESS
2020-12-01 13:47:18,405 DEBUG root:39 start: subiquity/InstallProgress/install/curtin_install/cmd-install/stage-curthooks/001-configure-apt/cmd-in-target: curtin command in-target
2020-12-01 13:47:32,907 DEBUG root:39 finish: subiquity/InstallProgress/install/curtin_install/cmd-install/stage-curthooks/001-configure-apt/cmd-in-target: SUCCESS: Status.FAIL
2020-12-01 13:47:32,909 DEBUG root:39 finish: subiquity/InstallProgress/install/curtin_install/cmd-install/stage-curthooks/001-configure-apt: SUCCESS: Status.FAIL
2020-12-01 13:47:32,911 DEBUG root:39 finish: subiquity/InstallProgress/install/curtin_install/cmd-install/stage-curthooks: SUCCESS: Status.FAIL
2020-12-01 13:47:33,100 DEBUG subiquitycore.utils:83 arun_command ['systemd-cat', '--level-prefix=false', '--identifier=curtin_log.6605', '/snap/subiquity/1966/usr/bin/python3', '-m', 'curtin', '--showtrace', '-c', '/var/log/installer/subiquity-curtin-install.conf', 'install'] exited with code 3
2020-12-01 13:47:33,100 DEBUG subiquity.lockfile:44 unlocking exclusive /run/subiquity/installing
2020-12-01 13:47:33,101 ERROR root:39 finish: subiquity/InstallProgress/install/curtin_install: FAIL: Command '['systemd-cat', '--level-prefix=false', '--identifier=curtin_log.6605', '/snap/subiquity/1966/usr/bin/python3', '-m', 'curtin', '--showtrace', '-c', '/var/log/installer/subiquity-curtin-install.conf', 'install']' returned non-zero exit status 3.
2020-12-01 13:47:33,103 ERROR subiquitycore.controller.installprogress:145 curtin_error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/snap/subiquity/1966/lib/python3.6/site-packages/subiquity/controllers/installprogress.py", line 304, in install
    await self.curtin_install(context=context)
  File "/snap/subiquity/1966/lib/python3.6/site-packages/subiquitycore/context.py", line 142, in decorated_async
    return await meth(self, **kw)
  File "/snap/subiquity/1966/lib/python3.6/site-packages/subiquity/controllers/installprogress.py", line 281, in curtin_install
    self.logged_command(curtin_cmd), check=True)
  File "/snap/subiquity/1966/lib/python3.6/site-packages/subiquitycore/utils.py", line 85, in arun_command
    raise subprocess.CalledProcessError(proc.returncode, cmd)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['systemd-cat', '--level-prefix=false', '--identifier=curtin_log.6605', '/snap/subiquity/1966/usr/bin/python3', '-m', 'curtin', '--showtrace', '-c', '/var/log/installer/subiquity-curtin-install.conf', 'install']' returned non-zero exit status 3.
2020-12-01 13:47:33,104 DEBUG subiquity.core:470 generating crash report
```

Answer (score 5):

The issue is caused when multiple network adapters are used. The issue goes away when only one NIC is used.

Comment: This was the first hint at a helpful solution. 
If you're running Ubuntu server in a VM (Gnome boxes, kvm, libvirt etc) Then remove any attached NIC's before you install the OS. Otherwise install fails with the above error. 
Not sure why this hasn't been fixed in mainstream. But I've spent 4 days trying to get Ubuntu to install in a virtual environment. Thanks for this helpful answer.