# Ubuntu Server 20.04.2 LTS: Failed Install on bare-metal dual-AMD server (install failed crashed with CalledProcessError)

Tags: server, 20.04, system-installation, crash, subiquity

I am a newer Ubuntu user embarking on my first bare-metal server build with Ubuntu Server (20.04.2 LTS).

**I'm encountering a failed installation with an odd error that I cannot seem to decipher (CalledProcessError)**. I am installing from a USB ISO, which I have already tried re-building twice to eliminate that as a possible error.

**System Info**: [Supermicro 4023S-TRT](https://www.supermicro.com/en/Aplus/system/Tower/4023/AS-4023S-TRT.cfm) & [Manual](https://www.supermicro.com/manuals/superserver/4U/MNL-2037.pdf)
**Specific Motherboard** (integrated with system): [Supermicro H11DSi-NT](https://www.supermicro.com/en/products/motherboard/H11DSi-NT) & [Manual](https://www.supermicro.com/manuals/motherboard/EPYC7000/MNL-2027.pdf)
**Other System Specs**: Dual AMD Epyc 7551 Processors (7001 Series Naples Core); 512 GB ECC DDR4-2666 memory; OS hard drive is a M.2 Samsung 980 (256 GB)

I removed all hard-disks except my OS hard disk (M.2 SSD drive) and tried installation again, I still have the same Failed Install. I was able to extract the Crash Logs. I pasted the most relevant section below (what I believe is most relevant). The Crash file is very large, I pasted the entire file underneath the snippet.

I cannot find good data on this "CalledProcessError". **Can anyone help provide direction?**

Other info requested in comments below: Output of `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version` and `free -h`

[image: Output of commands]

Snippets of Crash Logs below, I can provide more, these seemed most relevant.

```
2020-04-01 17:26:23,133 INFO subiquitycore.common.errorreport:406 saving crash report 'install failed crashed with CalledProcessError' to /var/crash/1585761983.132111549.install_fail.crash
```

---

```
Title: install failed crashed with CalledProcessError
Traceback:
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/snap/subiquity/2280/lib/python3.6/site-packages/subiquity/server/controllers/install.py", line 231, in install
     await self.curtin_install(context=context)
   File "/snap/subiquity/2280/lib/python3.6/site-packages/subiquitycore/context.py", line 148, in decorated_async
     return await meth(self, **kw)
   File "/snap/subiquity/2280/lib/python3.6/site-packages/subiquity/server/controllers/install.py", line 204, in curtin_install
     self.logged_command(curtin_cmd), check=True)
   File "/snap/subiquity/2280/lib/python3.6/site-packages/subiquitycore/utils.py", line 85, in arun_command
     raise subprocess.CalledProcessError(proc.returncode, cmd)
 subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['systemd-cat', '--level-prefix=false', '--identifier=subiquity_log.3751', '/snap/subiquity/2280/usr/bin/python3', '-m', 'curtin', '--showtrace', '-c', '/var/log/installer/subiquity-curtin-install.conf', 'install']' returned non-zero exit status 3.
```

---

Comment: Boot to the Ubuntu Live USB, in "Try Ubuntu" mode, open a terminal, and edit your question, and show me the output of `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version` and `free -h`. Also tell me the EXACT make/model of the server and/or motherboard.

Comment: FYI there was an almost identical error reported previously [Curtin error on autoinstall Ubuntu 20.04.1](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1296787/curtin-error-on-autoinstall-ubuntu-20-04-1)

Comment: @heynnema - added all requested information, welcome any thoughts. I ran these through the shell tool in the Ubuntu Server installer when the ISO boots, assuming that provides the correct output but can re-run using your exact instructions if necessary.

Comment: Your BIOS is current. AMD processors are funny about RAM. Although it'll take forever on your configuration, go to https://www.memtest86.com/ and download/run their free `memtest` to test your memory. Get at least one complete pass of all the 4/4 tests to confirm good memory. This may take many hours to complete.

Comment: @heynnema your idea was completely on-point. I actually discovered when poking through the BIOS this morning before the `memtest` route that not all the RAM was registering (7 of 8 DIMMS were showing). I re-slotted all RAM and now show full 512 GB. Ran install again, seems to be working, however I am having a separate unrelated issue with my VGA - HDMI adapter cable so I have to grab another monitor because I can't get video on my progress (need a native VGA monitor). Will report more later; hoping we are resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the comments...

Your BIOS is current. AMD processors are funny about RAM. Although it'll take forever on your configuration, go to https://www.memtest86.com/ and download/run their free memtest to test your memory. Get at least one complete pass of all the 4/4 tests to confirm good memory. This may take many hours to complete.

@heynnema your idea was completely on-point. I actually discovered when poking through the BIOS this morning before the memtest route that not all the RAM was registering (7 of 8 DIMMS were showing). I re-slotted all RAM and now show full 512 GB. Ran install again, seems to be working.