# curtin.util.ProcessExecutionError: Unexpected error while running command when trying to install ubuntu server

Tags: server, system-installation, python, 64-bit

I'm trying to install Ubuntu server 22.04 on my old PC.
After setting up and clicking up `install`, in some time I can see an error report `Sorry, there was a problem completing the installation`

It occurs during `installing kernel` stage.
I can see the next output at the end of full log:

```
curtin.util.ProcessExecutionError: unexpected error while running command.
Command: ['unsahre', '--fork', 'pid', '--', 'chroot', '/target', 'eatmydata', 'apt-get', '--quiet', '--assume-yes', '--option=Dpkg::options::=--force-unsafe-io', '--option=Dpkg::Options::=--force-confold', 'install', 'linux-generic']
Exit code: 100
Reason: -
Stdout: ''
Stderr: ''
```

My PC:

- MB: Evga nforce 680i sli
- Processor: Intel Core2 Quad CPU Q660 2.40GHz
- 6 Gb DDR2 memory

What I've tried:

- Installation with and without plugged ethernet cable
- Installation with and without updating installer to latest version
- Installing Ubuntu 20.04 server (same error)
- Installation to different HDD (I've tried different SATA and IDE disks)
- Installation with disabled network adapters (from [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1296787/curtin-error-on-autoinstall-ubuntu-20-04-1))

I should also mention that I've managed to boot live Manjaro distro sucessfully.

Let me know if I can add some more information about this.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the problem was in damaged image. After burning my boot stick with fresh-downloaded image by another program, installation complete successfully.